# javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

Tags: java, exception, cryptography, struts, javabeans

How to Solve below Problem.

**`action.java`:**

```
byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
account_bean fromBean = (account_bean) form;
String account_name = fromBean.getName();
String encrypted_password = fromBean.getPassword();
String account_password = AESencrp.decrypt(encrypted_password.toString().trim());
```

**`AESencrp.java`:**

```
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import sun.misc.*;
public class AESencrp 
{
 private static final String ALGO = "AES";
private static final byte[] keyValue = 
    new byte[] { 'T', 'h', 'e', 'B', 'e', 's', 't',
 'S', 'e', 'c', 'r','e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' };
 public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception 
 {
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
    String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
    return encryptedValue.toString().trim();
 }
 public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception 
 {
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
    String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
    return decryptedValue.toString().trim();
 }   
 private static Key generateKey() throws Exception 
 {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
    return key;
 }
 }
```

**Error:**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
```

Comment: NEVER encrypt password into the database, because they can be decripted. HASH them with a one-way hashing algorithm, then hash the one provided by the user and check if they're the same: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14683668/1654265

Answer (score 0):

Use `UTF8` charset to encode/decode a string.

to encode

```
Data.getBytes("UTF8")
```

to decode

```
new String(decValue, "UTF8")
```