# Hiding param of struts.xml values in Struts 2

Tags: java, url, struts2, passwords, url-parameters

Is there any way to hide the `param` values in `struts.xml` as they are visible on the URL when I pass them from one action to another?

```xml
<action name="BackToManagerIndex" class="Action.LoginAction" method="ManagerList">         
    <result type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">login</param>
        <param name="namespace">../Manager</param>
        <param name="User_Id">%{User_Id} </param>
        <param name="Password">%{Password}</param>
    </result>
```

Here when ever the `BackToManagerIndex` action is completed I am redirecting it to another action called `login` which is in namespace manager with 2 properties: `User_Id` and `Password`.

Every thing is fine but the values of both the properties are visible on the URL as

> `http://localhost:8084/MEMS/Manager/login.action?User_Id=abc%40gmail.com&Password=1234`

Is there any way to hide these values or the URL can be set to

> `http://localhost:8084/MEMS/Manager/login.action`
>   ?

<sub>(I still should get the values at other action)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters that are included with the `redirectAction` result type are reflected in the URL. To remove them from the URL you need to remove them from the result config.

```xml
<action name="BackToManagerIndex" class="Action.LoginAction" method="ManagerList">
    <result type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">login</param>
        <param name="namespace">/Manager</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

Another action after redirecting should take parameters from the session.

Answer (score 2):

You should never carry a password like that, in fact you should not even store it in the session. Not even in the database.

You should instead hash it and store the hash in the database, then when an user enters a password to log in, you hash the password inserted and confront it with the hash on database.

In this way, not even you, the system and database administrator, are aware of the user's passwords.

Then hackers will try to use rainbow tables, dictionaries of hashed passwords, and to prevent that, you will add some salt to the hash.

Read more on:

- [Struts2: how to store safety username and password from action to action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22256264/1654265)
- [Update object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14683668/1654265)

---

Password discussion apart, if you want to redirect avoiding the parameters in the url **for a user *experience reason*** (and **NOT for a *security reason***), other than putting them in Session you can also

> run a script in the landing page that make use of [HTML5 **History API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history):

```
<script>
    // BEFORE:
    // http://localhost:8084/MEMS/Manager/login.action?User_Id=abc%40gmail.com&Password=1234
    window.history.pushState("","",window.location.pathname);
    // LATER:
    // http://localhost:8084/MEMS/Manager/login.action
</script>
```